# Exception Details screen in Windows Azure production

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure

I have an ASP.NET MVC project which is published on Windows Azure.
If some unhandled exception occurs while I run this project locally - it shows a special "Death page" also known as "Exception Details Yellow Screen" with a full stack trace, piece of code where the error occured, etc. 
However if I run in production mode - it only shows the default error view placed in ../Views/Shared/Error.cshtml

The question is: how can I show the same "Yellow Screen" in production mode too?

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing here is the default asp.net behavior (not specific to windows azure).  In order to see the error message you would have to turn off custom errors in your web.config and republish.

Comment: Thank you for reply. However custom errors are not turned on in any of Web.config file in my app.
BTW which of the config file should I modify? I have three:
Web.Debug.config and Web.Release.config in the root project folder and one more Web.config in the Views subfolder.

Comment: It depends on the configuration setting you are using to publish. Most likely you are using "Release", in which case, it would be Web.Release.config.

Comment: Actually, it turns out that when you do a publish from windows azure, it ignore the transforms contains in the .Release.config or .Debug.config.  Change it in the "root" Web.config

Comment: You probably have this on a RemoteOnly setting which explains the difference. It is also the default. You'll want to set it to off. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc(v=vs.71).aspx